# How do you cumulatively aggregate string in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, cumulative-sum

I have a column that contains strings.

```
                 Rm
0                Rwws,xxALd
1                Ras,yySAw
2                Bdbbd1dd
```

I want to cumulatively aggregate the string through the y-axis.

This is the desired output.

```
                 Rm
0                Rwws,xxALd
1                Rwws,xxALdRas,yySAw
2                Rwws,xxALdRas,yySAwBdbbd1dd
```

Something like this can be achieved using the expanding or cumsum() function, however it appears to work for numeric attributes only.

Comment: `df['Rm']=df['Rm'].cumsum()`?

Comment: I have tried again and it works now. It wasn't working before because of missing values.

Comment: Out of curiosity: how do missing values show up in a column that has a string type? Aren't they blank strings? Or are they `None`?

Comment: @BorutFlis If there are `NaN` then fill them with empty character `df['Rm']=df['Rm'].fillna('').cumsum()`

Comment: @9769953 They are NaN.

Comment: NaN? Just seems odd; I assume the whole column then has dtype 'object'?

Comment: Yes the dtype is object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    col1
0   I
1   am
2   cool
```

a quick idea

```
df.apply(lambda x: x+',').cumsum().str.strip(',')
```

output:

```
0            I
1         I,am
2    I,am,cool
```

or just:

```
df.cumsum()
```

output:

```
0          I
1        Iam
2    Iamcool
```

Comment: I tested:   
col1
0  I
1  am,
2  cool

output:
0             I
1          I,am
2    I,am,,cool

Comment: you can remove `stip(',')`. Adjust the code to your will